# External USB/hard drive

Tags: xbox-360

So, I just got an xbox360 without a hard drive, and my parents got me a 1TB hard drive called " My passport ultra" and after we formatted it and everything, my console is still not allowing me to play Xbox original games. what did we do wrong?

Comment: Are you just downloading Xbox games?  That's not going to work; you still have to buy them.

Comment: No, I have games from the original Xbox that I want to play but when I put a game in its says to connect a Xbox hard drive.

Comment: Is it a 3.0 device? Speed still needs to be up to par to handle it. IIRC it still requires USB 3.0 speeds

Answer (score 1):

On the Xbox 360, you cannot connect external storage and use it as an official Xbox Hard drive.

Source(s):

> You can play some original Xbox games on your Xbox 360 console if you
>   have an official Xbox 360 Hard Drive.

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/legacy-devices/original-console/play-original-games

Also, "supported content" on the Xbox 360 page shows that you can only run Xbox games from an official Xbox 360 Hard drive.

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/storage